# Show that $n= 5 + 5^2+ 5^3+...5^{150}$ is divisible by $930$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that $n= 5 + 5^2+ 5^3+...5^{150}$ is divisible by $930$.

I'm thinking to show that $n$ is divisible by each of the prime factors of $930$, is that right? I'm stuck

Comment: $$930 = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 31$$  Can you show $n$ is divisible by any of those factors?

Comment: Since $930=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot31$, and $n$ is always a multiple of 5, by other hand, the sum has a even quantity of terms, $n$ is multiple of 2.

Answer (score 3):

Another short variant:

- divisibility by $30$; group terms by consecutive pairs:
  $$n= (\underbrace{5 + 5^2}_{=30})(1+ 5^2+\dots+5^{148}).$$
- divisibility by $31$: group by three consecutive numbers:
  $$n=5(\underbrace{1+5+5^2}_{=31})(1+ 5^3+\dots+5^{147}).$$

Answer (score 2):

$$n= 5(1 +5+ 5^2+ ...5^{149})  = 5 {5^{150}-1\over 4}$$

so $5\mid 4n\implies 5\mid n$. Now:

$$5^{150}-1 = 125^{50}-1 = (125-1)(125^{49}+...+125^2+125+1) $$

so $31\mid 4n \implies 31\mid n$ and $$5^{150}-1 = 25^{75}-1 = (25-1)(25^{74}+...+25+1) $$

so $24\mid 4n \implies 6\mid n$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Render $930=2×3×5×31$, which is square-free, and test for divisibility by each prime factor.

Divisibility by 2 $\to$ even number of odd terms, $\color{blue}{\text{passes}}$.

Divisibility by 3 $\to$ even number of terms with alternating residues $+1,-1\bmod 3, \color{blue}{\text{passes}}$

Divisibility by 5$\to$ each term is separately divisible, $\color{blue}{\text{passes}}$.

Divisibility by 31 $\to$ terms cycle in residue:  $\overline{5,25,1}$, cycle adds up to zero and the number of terms is a multiple of the period (3); $\color{blue}{\text{passes}}$.

And we're good.

Answer (score 0):

As $\sum_{r=1}^n5^r=\dfrac{5(5^n-1)}{5-1}$

Clearly it is divisible by $5$ as each term is divisible by $5$

Now the sum will be even for $n$ is even $=2m$(say)

As the denominator $(4)$ is relatively prime with $3\cdot31$

It's sufficient to establish $5^{2m}-1$ is divisible by $93$

As $(5,93)=1,$ the sufficient condition will be by https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function $$\lambda(93)=\cdots=30$$ should divide $2m$

So, it is sufficient to have $n=2m$ be divisible by $30$

Answer (score 0):

$1+5+5^2+\dots+5^{150}=\dfrac{1-5^{151}}{1-5}$.

Now by lil Fermat, this is $1\pmod {2, 3, 31}$ respectively.

It's $1\pmod 5$ too.

Therefore by the Chinese remainder theorem,  it's $1 \pmod {930}$.

Comment: Even if Fermat is lil', he requires an uppercase F… ;o)

Comment: The leading $1$ of the sum is a misread in the question...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms The leading $1$ is essential to the solution.  The last step would be to subtract it from each side.

Comment: @Bernard right you are

Answer (score 0):

$N=5 + .... + 5^{150} = 5(1+...... + 5^{149} = 5\cdot \frac {5^{150}-1}{4}$.

$930| N \iff $

$4*930| 4*N = 5(5^{150}-1) \iff $

$\frac {4*930}5=\frac{4*93*10}5=4*93*2|5^{150}-1\iff$

$8*3*31|5^{150}-1\iff$

$8|5^{150}-1$ and $3|5^{150}-1$ and $31|5^{150}-1\iff$

$5^{150}\equiv 1\pmod {8,3,31}$.

And we can's Euler's Th|Fermat's Little Theorem to prove those.

$\phi(8=2^3) = 2^2 = 4$ so $5^4\equiv 1\pmod 8$.  But actually $5^2 =25 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ so $5^{150}\equiv (5^2)^{75}\equiv 1\pmod 8$.

ANd $5^{2}\equiv 1\pmod 3$ so $5^{150}\equiv (5^2)^{75}\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

$5^{30}\equiv 1 \pmod {31}$ so $5^{150}\equiv (5^{30})^5\equiv 1 \pmod{31}$.

That's it.